# Angular 7: column width

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular7

I have an issue in Angular 7.

I have created 3 columns. It is possible to change the width of the first and the second columns and the last one is is calculated consequently. When the window width is portrait, the first 2 columns disappear.

The issue is that the third column doesn't change its width in portrait status, but it is less than 100% (as written in the CSS file). How can I make it 100% for mobile view?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

Comment: I have already tried it, but it doesn't work: the third column is still less than 100%

Comment: We need to see more of your code to understand what's happening. You can check how to right a valid example here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve